# Is it possible to integrate apple pay with android apps? [React Native]

Tags: android, react-native, payment-gateway, applepay

Is it possible to integrate apple pay into android apps? [React Native]

I want to integrate apple pay with react native app, and I can't see a way or docs to add apple pay to the android app, Is it possible or not?

Tired to google the topic

Comment: Yes, use the Apple Pay JS API. Either try to include it directly or create a WebView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pay is Apple's mobile payment app, meaning **it won't work on Android devices**. You need an iPhone 6 (or Plus), an iPhone 6S (or Plus), or an Apple Watch to use Apple Pay.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250156753